# url файла для открытия его в браузере

Tags: java

Пост запросом отправляю файл на сервер, он там сохраняется в папку, и в базу данных я должен сохранить url ссылку на этот файл, что бы её просто можно было ввести в браузер и открыть в файл. Подскажите как это сделать на Java.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы передать файл из папки в браузер, нужен rest-метод, который будет выдавать файл по каким-то параметрам (id, название или что-то ещё). С учётом эндпоинта этого метода конструируйте url и сохраняйте его в бд.